# Starting an activity from a background service and wait for it to be created

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a Background service that sometimes needs to start an activity. I would like to wait for this activity to be created (that is OnCreate() has exited).

Once the activity has been created it has registered for receiving messages.

I'd like the background service to send a message once the activity is created.

How can I do the waiting without blocking?

Comment: We could create service and broadcast receiver to create non stop service. when service going to stop it restarts it again by sending broadcast. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/122868/broadcastreceiver-cant-start-service-on-boot-reboot

Answer (score 0):

Well I ended up with using an IOC container to share an object instance between the the two contexts. This object would contain an AsyncAutoResetEvent for the activity to set and the service to await.